# The use of $(this) in jQuery

Tags: jquery

When writing code using jQuery i find myself using var self = $(this) to reference the current context of the object i'm in. For example:

```
$('#myDiv').click(function(e){

var self = $(this);

self.css('background', 'red');

});
```

This is great but I have to repeat this process for every object. Example:

```
$('#myDiv').hover(function(){

//hover over function
var self = $(this);
self.css('background', 'red');

}, function(){

//hover out function
var self = $(this);
self.css('background', 'blue');

});
```

My question is is there any way i can set a global variable of self and use it to reference the context i'm in. So i want to gloably set self = $(this) and no matter where i use it it will automatically reference the current object i'm in?

Comment: Why not just do `$(this).css` instead of assigning it to a variable?

Comment: You should only store `$(this)` in a variable if you are using it more than once in the same scope/function. In your sample code, it isn't needed.

Comment: You are doing something crazy. It's not an optimization, nor is it any clearer, to alias `$(this)` this way. There is no way to set a global variable that magically will figure out which object is `this` at the moment.

Comment: @andrew = i'm trying to avoid writing $(this) all over the place. It's ugly to me in the code. This is more for code organization than anything else.

Comment: i guess @sorpigal answered my question lol.

Answer (score 6):

You can user directly `$(this).call()` without problems

Answer (score 3):

try:

```
var myDiv = $('#myDiv');

myDiv.hover(function(){
    myDiv.css('background', 'red');
}, function(){
    myDiv.css('background', 'blue');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

To reuse `$(this)` within same scope you can store it locally as you're currently doing.

```
$('#myDiv').hover(function(){
  var self = $(this);

  self.css('background', 'red');
  // reusing example
  self.find('some').foo();
}, function(){
  var self = $(this);

  self.css('background', 'blue');
  // reusing example
  self.bar();
});
```

You can also use `$(this)` it self

```
$('#myDiv').hover(function(){
  $(this).css('background', 'red');
}, function(){
  $(this).css('background', 'blue');
});
```

But declaring `self` outside of `hover` scope **(unnecessary for your case, I think)**

```
var self = null; // declare self as global

$('#myDiv').hover(function(){
  self = $(this);
}, function(){
  self = $(this);
});
```

Comment: How would declaring `self` as a global be beneficial if you simply overwrite it locally every time? All it does is keep the reference around longer after the last use, using more memory.

Answer (score 1):

Declaring outside hover function could make you use the same self variable in both hover functions but I would recommend you use #(this) instead of self.

```
var self = $(this);
$('#myDiv').hover(function(){

//hover over function

self.css('background', 'red');
//$(this).css('background', 'red'); //use this is better and more expressive
}, function(){

//hover out function
var self = $(this);
self.css('background', 'blue');
//$(this).css('background', 'red'); //use this is better and more expressive
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use jquerys data method instead of using global variables, http://api.jquery.com/data/

Set:

```
$('body').data({ myVar: $(this) });
```

Get:

```
var myVar = $('body').data('myVar');
```

Answer (score 0):

**[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/igohov/edit#javascript,html,live)**

You can create a function that will toggle your backgrounds for all the elements holded inside the function argument `(el)`:

```
function myFunction(el){

   $(el).hover(function(){
       $(this).css('background', 'red');
   }, function(){
       $(this).css('background', 'blue');
   });

}
```

Than you just call your function and use your desired element:

```
myFunction('#myDiv');
```

You can easily create a list of desired elements like:

```
myFunction('#myDiv, #anotherDiv, #heading1, .classes');
```